# Google API is showing only one city belongs to zipcode

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps

```
   //when the user clicks off of the zip field:
$('input[name="step2_code_postal"]').blur(function(){
    var zip = $(this).val();
    var city = '';

    //make a request to the google geocode api

    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+zip).success(function(response){
        //find the city        
        var address_components = response.results[0].address_components;
        $.each(address_components, function(index, component){
            var types = component.types;
            $.each(types, function(index, type){
                if(type == 'locality') {
                    console.log(component.long_name);
                    city = component.long_name;
                }
            });
        });

        //pre-fill the city
        $('input[name="step2_type_operation_ville"]').val(city);
    });
});
```

I am using this code and this is resulting only one city doesn't matter there are more than one cities belongs to one Zip Code.

For Example: 56140 has many cities in France and 21000 has only one city in France. 
[image]

[image]

Please help.

Comment: using `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=56140` as the url it returns a place called `Ihlen` in `Pipestone County, Minnesota`

Comment: But 56140 also exists in France and has many cities.

Comment: It looks like you might need to try `region code biasing` - for example `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=21000&region=FR` returns a result in Dijon. A list of region codes - http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry

Comment: Thanks, this(region=FR) was the problem.